# TestCafe assertion fails

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, assertion

I have a problem with .expect method which I cannot find a good solution for. In my test case after a certain step I am clicking on a button. This button-click opens a new page with the error text "Something went wrong". Now I would like to assert on that error text which has the selector `body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1`.

But every time this page is opened and the error is shown in the Console I get following error " AssertionError: object tested must be an array, an object, or a string, but undefined given"

I have tested `.expect(errorMessage.value).eql('Something went wrong')`.
I have also tested with `.expect(errorMessage.value).contains('Something went wrong')`
I have also tested `.expect(errorMessage.exists).ok()` and then "eql"

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is likely that the errorMessage Selector returns nothing. This may happen if your Selector is wrong or your element is invisible. To check the issue locally, please provide me with a link to your page and define the tested element.

Comment: Hi Marion. Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Unfortunately this is a company internal page which I cannot share and even if I do you cannot access it from the outside. Any tips on what I can do on my own?

Comment: Here is the HTML code if it helps:

`<error-page><div>
    <h1 class="mb-2 font-weight-bold">Something went wrong</h1>
    <div class="mb-4">
        <!----><ul class="list-unstyled">
            <!----><li>
                <span class="alert-iconed my-1"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!---->
    </div>`

Comment: Please also send me your "errorMessage" selector code.

Comment: Hi Marion,
Not sure I understand what you want exactly. The selector for the error message "Something went wrong" is "body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1" as written in the initial post.

If you want the selector for the "error page" element then it is "body > app > main > div > error-page"

Comment: Amir, please let me know how you defined the errorMessage variable. For example: const errorMessage = Selector("body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1") or var errorMessage = Selector("#elementID")

Comment: :-) You just solved my issue. 

I had  this.erroMessage = 'body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1';

Now after changing to:  this.erroMessage = Selector('body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1');  it works :-)

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, Amir! I've just moved a comment to an Answer so that the solution is available for other users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) to define the errorMessage variable. For example:

```
const errorMessage = Selector("body > app > main > div > error-page > div > h1")
```

or

```
var errorMessage = Selector("#elementID")
```